# How do I find the maximum value between several specific nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

EXAMPLE:
A unidirectional graph of the following type is given:

```
CREATE 
(b0:Bar {id:1, value: 1}),
(b1:Bar {id:2, value: 4}),
(b2:Bar {id:3, value: 3}),
(b3:Bar {id:4, value: 5}),
(b4:Bar {id:5, value: 9}),
(b5:Bar {id:6, value: 7}),
(b0)-[:NEXT_BAR]->(b1),
(b1)-[:NEXT_BAR]->(b2),
(b2)-[:NEXT_BAR]->(b3),
(b3)-[:NEXT_BAR]->(b4),
(b4)-[:NEXT_BAR]->(b5);

MATCH (b1)->[*1..5]->(b2)->(b3)->[*1..5]->(b4)
WHERE // here you need to write a condition that the maximum value between the value of nodes b3 and b4 is greater than the maximum value of nodes b1 and b2
RETURN //b1_b2_max, b3_b4_max
```

In other words, the result should be as follows:

```
b1_b2_max | b3_b4_max
4         | 9
```

Can you tell me how I can find aggregated information between certain nodes (including these nodes)?
What should my request look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to get the right values.

```
// start with a set of slices you would like to get the max from
WITH [[1,3],[3,5]] AS slices

// match the path you want to get the slices from
MATCH path=(:Bar {id: 1})-[:NEXT_BAR*..5]->(end:Bar)
WHERE NOT (end)-->()
WITH slices, path

// look at the nodes in each slice of the path 
UNWIND slices AS slice

// find the max value in the slice
  UNWIND nodes(path)[slice[0]..slice[1]] AS b
  RETURN 'b' + toString(slice[0]) + '_b' + toString(slice[1]-1) + '_max', max(b.value) AS max_value
```

Rather than returning the slice and max values in rows you can instead collect them as pairs and convert that to a map using `apoc.map.fromPairs`. Then access specific values in the map and return them as columns.

```
WITH [[1,3],[3,5]] AS slices
MATCH path=(:Bar {id: 1})-[:NEXT_BAR*..5]->(end:Bar)
WHERE NOT (end)-->()
WITH slices, path
UNWIND slices AS slice
  UNWIND nodes(path)[slice[0]..slice[1]] AS b
  WITH ['b' + toString(slice[0]) + '_b' + toString(slice[1]-1) + '_max', max(b.value)] AS pair
WITH collect(pair) AS pairs
RETURN apoc.map.fromPairs(pairs)['b1_b2_max'] AS b1_b2_max, 
apoc.map.fromPairs(pairs)['b3_b4_max'] AS b3_b4_max
```